# swagger-codegen: errors with \d+ patterns and type: "array"

Tags: html, swagger

I'm a newbie to Swagger. I've used the swagger servlet to generate my swagger.json file from our REST API Java classes. The swagger.json file shows swagger 2.0 (I assume this is the 2.0 schema version). There was nothing fancy in the source files, just @Api and a few @ApiOperation annotations.

Then I tried using swagger-codegen-cli (both version 2.1.4 and 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT, the latest) to generate HTML output from the JSON file. I got the following results on both:

```
reading from dsm_swagger.json
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name suppressed
[main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - skipping invalid property {
    "type" : "array"
}
writing file /home/combs/dsm_swagger/./index.html
```

So I get an output file, but any types that are flagged as lists of objects are not handled correctly. These do appear to be valid 2.0 constructs.

I'm also getting Jackson errors about invalid escape characters because it sees

```
"pattern": "\d+"
```

in the file. I can work around the \d by using [0-9], but assume it should be handled as is.

Has anybody seen these particular issues and know if they're either fixed or there is a workaround in swagger-codegen or the source file? Is swagger-codegen actually handling v2.0 specs correctly? Any pointers to up to date info or code would be appreciated!

EDIT:
As mentioned in a comment, by using "@JsonIgnore" and "@JsonProperty" in appropriate places and upgrading to V1.5.6 of swagger-core, I got around the issues with invalid property and type "array" messages. Here's an example of the issue with \d:

```
"/v1/admins/{adminId}": {
  "put": {
    "tags": [
      "admins"
    ],
    "summary": "Update information about a particular admin, given its ID. The update information is passed in the POST body.",
    "description": "Longer notes about what this does",
    "operationId": "updateUser",
    "consumes": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "adminId",
        "in": "path",
        "required": true,
        "type": "integer",
        "pattern": "\d+",
        "format": "int64"
      },
      {
        "in": "body",
        "name": "body",
        "required": false,
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/UserUpdateInfo"
        }
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "successful operation",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/UserInfo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

This is the exact output of swagger-core, and yet swagger-codegen fails with the following:

```
 combs@dcombs-lap:~/dsm_swagger$ gen_file
 reading from dsm_swagger.json
 reading from dsm_swagger.json
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape 'd' (code 100)
   at [Source: dsm_swagger.json; line: 411, column: 27]
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._handleUnrecognizedCharacterEscape(ParserMinimalBase.java:485)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._decodeEscaped(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2924)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2209)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2165)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:279)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:224)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeArray(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:262)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:221)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:218)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:218)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:218)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:62)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:14)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3066)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1861)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:139)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:74)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:73)
   at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:317)
   at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:186)
   at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
   at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:89)
   at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:188)
   at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
combs@dcombs-lap:~/dsm_swagger$
```

Comment: Found the answer. The first item about 'missing property for name suppressed' I thought meant "we've suppressed a missing "name" property". Actually it's "there is a missing entry in the declaration of the property named 'suppressed'. Turns out it was a type: array declaration, but apparently swagger-codegen is seeing the list after type erasure. Still looking for solution. Also, still haven't found why \d is considered invalid, if swagger is generating the file like this. I think modifying the file to use \\d will work, but it would be better if swagger generated a correct file.

Comment: Please share the output of your swagger.json?

Comment: I fixed the problems with **suppressed** and other errors by using "@JsonIgnore" and "@JsonProperty" appropriately, and by upgrading to use V1.5.6 of swagger-core (all online references I saw only mention V1.5.0). I'll attach a relevant part of the swagger.json (the whole thing is 10K+ lines).

Comment: The `\d` is invalid because the escaping is processed by the Java compiler.  It should be `\\d` in the string literal, which ends up compiling back to `\d`.  For example, in Java, `String newline = "\n";` gives a string with 1 character - the newline.  `String backslashN = "\\n";` results in a 2 character string, `\n`.